Another question about the fixed point and group action.
Let $G$ be a group of order 15 that acts on a set $X$ of 7 elements.
$a)$ Prove that exist a fixed point.
$b)$ If X is a group and $G$ acts by authomorphism. What can we conclude about the fixed points?
For $a)$ if there where none fixed point, by the orbit stabilizer theorem, we get $7=3k+5m$ for some positive integres $k,m$, imposible.
For part $b)$ If $X$ is a group then the fixed points are a subgroup of $X$, so there is a unique fixed point or the action is trivial. It's okay the conclusion or there is something better we can conclude?

Why there cannot be,  for example, 2 fixed points and 1 orbit of size 5?

I think I answered myself: because then $\sum|Stab(x)|=45\ne$ $k+(7-k)7=\sum|Fix(g)|$, for every nonnegative integer $k$. So, I think your answer is fine.
